# How to use XPath to select an element whose style does not contain display: none and exclude its child elements

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

My code looks like this:

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

s = Selector(text="""
<div id="content">

<div style="display: none;">
    <div>123</div>
</div>

<img></img>
</div>
""")

res = s.xpath("//div[@id='content']//*[not(contains(@style,'display: none;'))]").extract()
print(res)
```

I'm looking forward to it：

```
<img></img>
```

but:

```
['<div>123</div>', '<img>']
```

I want to get elements where display is not equal to none, Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: Or you can use regular expressions.As long as this function can be realized

Comment: There is no <img> in your `Selector`. Where did you get it?

Comment: @starryrbs use `edit` button to update your question

Comment: @JaSON It's changed

Comment: @gangabass It's changed

Answer (score 2):

Try below XPath to get not *which doesn't have `style="display: none;"` and doesn't have any ancestor with `style="display: none;"`*

```
//div[@id='content']//*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[contains(@style,'display: none;')])]
```

Comment: Yes, I tested it. It can solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: There is still a problem. Although all the contents have been obtained, the structure of this writing has changed

Comment: @starryrbs , can you share more details? or create new question regarding new problem

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I find lxml can solve my problem